# fetchone() is setting int variable to tuple

Tags: python, variables, sqlite, integer, tuples

I have a project with Python 2.7 and SQLite3.

I am trying to store an integer variable in an SQLite3 database column, and then later be able to set a variable to the value of the SQLite column.

The connection is fine, the column exists, and it is type "int".

I am using this code to pull the data:

```
    Trailcrest.fish_score = c.execute("SELECT fish_score FROM roster WHERE agentnumber = ?;", (AN,) ).fetchone()
```

The "AN" variable I'm calling is provided as an argument when the def this code is contained in is called.

However, when I look at the Trailcrest.fish_score variable, while the data has been written to it, it has been written as a tuple, and not as an integer. The variable originally contained an integer.

What is going on? How can I fix it? (I'm assuming I need to do some casting, but I'm not sure.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`fetchone()`](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone) still returns a Row-like object, which you'll need to parse the lone field out of it, so you'll need to get the data out of it

```
row = c.execute("SELECT fish_score FROM roster WHERE agentnumber = ?;", (AN,) ).fetchone()
if row is not None:  # or just "if row"
    Trailcrest.fish_score = row[0]
else:
    pass # didn't get back a row
```

Comment: It works! Thank you. As a note to anyone who uses this code, make sure you put something under "else:", other than a comment, or the compiler will be mad at you.

Comment: @Jason: the `pass` keyword was created for that purpose (placeholder).